# Where is the official C# compiler from the .NET SDK package?

Tags: c#, .net-8.0

I am trying to compile a C# file using the official compiler included in the .NET SDK package without using the Visual Studio IDE.

The package is installed in

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101
```

but where is the compiler binary executable?

Comment: Use dotnet build -v detailed, shows lots of details including the compile command.  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Roslyn\bincore\csc.dll on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your operating system and .NET version you can find the compiler (= "Roslyn") `csc.dll` at:

- Linux: `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/<version>/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll`
- Windows: `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\<version>\Roslyn\bincore\csc.dll`

However usually you would use the [dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/) to do everything that some IDEs do for you.

- Compile project/ solution: [`dotnet build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build)
- Run project: [`dotnet run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run)
- Run tests: [`dotnet test`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test)
- ...

The CLI can do much more like adding projects to solutions, install global tools, create NuGet packages etc. so you should really check that out especially if you plan to develop without an full-featured IDE.